# How can a user with 0 activity have 174 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

I saw [this profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/92878?tab=stats) on Area51. The user has 0 Proposals, 0 Current Commitments, 0 Fulfilled commitments, 0 Followed, 0 Example question and has 174 reputation. Looking at [reputation changes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/92878/40-love?tab=reputation) it shows.

> There aren't yet any reputation changes to show

My question is How can a user with 0 activity have 174 reputation or is there another type of association bonus on area51?

Comment: Deleted content?

Comment: Seems to have proposed a Tennis site. And that proposal no longer exists. It might have had some activity there.

Comment: @animuson I thought reputation for upvotes on deleted content is revoked???

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi I'm fairly sure that the same "keep your reputation" deletion rules for 60 days / 3 upvotes still applies to Area 51.

Comment: Area51 is a different fork of the SE software.  It's entirely possible that the rules work differently there.  I'd say it's fair to let someone keep their rep from example questions; it's not their fault that a proposal failed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay. Thanks!!!. You could add it as an answer

Comment: @animuson I understand now. Thanks

Comment: @Bart yep, [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EoXMQBUidvMJ:area51.stackexchange.com/users/92878/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) confirms that. :)

Comment: Maybe association bonus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have 151 reputation [there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/46868?tab=stats) as well without any activity whatsoever. So:

1. Yes there is the +100 association bonus when you have account with 200 rep elsewhere. Unlike on other sites, it does not show in the reputation history but it's there:

   > [image]
2. There is 50 reputation bonus for confirming your email address, as mentioned in the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).
3. In addition the user in question had proposed a site and it had follower: each is +5 reputation and according to [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EoXMQBUidvMJ:area51.stackexchange.com/users/92878/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) it had at least 6 followers, i.e. +30 net reputation which is kept when the proposal is removed:

   > [image]

The above results in (at least) 181 rep, remove some for downvotes and you got it solved. :)